# Spliting the column in CSV its showing attribute Error in QGIS plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pandas

I am trying create a new plugin in QGIS. I have my own script its work in normal Jupyter Notebook, then I planned to convert into as QGIS Plugin.The dout/error occur while spliting the columns.

```
    def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""        
    if self.first_start == True:
        self.first_start = False
        self.dlg = DegreesminutessecondstodecimaldegreesDialog()
        self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.select_output_file)


    # Fetch the currently loaded layers
    layers = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().children()
    self.dlg.MapLayerComboBox.addItems([layer.name() for layer in layers])
#Connecting to selected layer
    def layer_changed(layer):
        self.dlg.FieldComboBox.setLayer(layer)
        self.dlg.FieldComboBox_2.setLayer(layer)
    self.dlg.MapLayerComboBox.layerChanged.connect(layer_changed)  

    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed


    if result:
        def D_D():
            DD = self.dlg.MapLayerComboBox.layerChanged.connect(layer_changed)

            lat = self.dlg.FieldComboBox.currentField()
            lon = self.dlg.FieldComboBox_2.currentField()

            g = pd.DataFrame(lat.str.split(expand=True).tolist(),
                             columns=['1', 'D1', 'D2', '4', 'M1', 'M2', '7', 'S1', 'S2', '10'])
```

I run its show error in

```
g = pd.DataFrame(lat.str.split(expand=True).tolist(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

When I remove str before split

```
g = pd.DataFrame(lat.split("").tolist(),
ValueError: empty separator
```

Can you give me some ideas to make this work?

Comment: as was explained https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/397129/qgis-plugin-builder-error you can't have an empty separator - either put a space between the " or leave them out.

Comment: when leave space between ' '  g = pd.DataFrame(lat.split(' ',9).tolist(),
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tolist'

Comment: you don't need to convert a list (the output of split) to a list - so `g = pd.DataFrame(lat.split())` should work fine